# IIS Redirect subdomain to a specific site and port

Tags: c#, iis, windows-server

I have a Windows Server 2019 with IIS installed.

Application Request Routing and Url Rewrite modules are installed too.

I have 2 sites (asp.net applications) :

```
- Site1 / port 443
- Site2 / port 4431
```

I have

```
- mydomain.com
- sub1.mydomain.com

both configured to go to my Windows Server thanks to a DNS A record.
```

Now I would like to configure IIS to be able to

```
1. redirect 'mydomain.com' to Site1 on port 443
2. redirect 'sub1.mydomain.com' to Site2 on port 4431
```

> 1 : already OK with a simple IIS binding and the DNS record

> **2 : where I need help**

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You should save yourself from all kinds of trouble, by putting such sites at port 443 with SNI, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html

Comment: You can set the port of `mydomain.com` to 443, so you can use redirection directly, such as `<action type="Redirect" url="http://Site1" />`.

Comment: thanks @LexLi but I don't want to use third parties, a pure IIS solution must exists

Comment: @samwu mydomain.com is already set to the the 443 port and I want sub1.mydomain.com to be set on the 4431 port where "Site 2" is listening. But I don't want "Site2" to be part of the URL or any redirection, it's just the nickname of my application

Comment: In the article I linked, everything under "Background" is IIS native knowledge,  and you don't need to use any third party tool. You can review HTTP API settings on your machine via `netsh http` as it contains the equivalent information.